# query submit form and get at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, get, submit

I want to do an ajax `get` on the submission of a form or on the click on the submit button but the form submits before the `get` can do it's thing.

I have tried this:

```
jQuery('#submit_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('blabla');
    $('#iform').trigger('submit');
```

and

```
$('#iform').submit();

});
```

This doesn't submit the form at all but the `get` works. Please help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is **asynchronous**..

Try this

```
 jQuery('#submit_btn').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.get('blabla', function() {
          $('#iform').trigger('submit'); 
       });
});
```

You need to trigger it in the callback handler.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I think my problem is I am doing a cross origin get.  I do not want a response back but I am just submitting the info.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks but thsi doesn't even work: ` jQuery('#submit_btn').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

          $('#iform').trigger('submit'); 

});'

Answer (score 0):

If your using **AJAX** then I assume that you **dont want to refresh the page?** try using `<input type='button' id='submit_btn' value='Submit'>` because using `type='submit'` refreshes the page. try using a `type='button'` I hope this helps.